# Как правильно сверстать табы на флексах?

Tags: css, flexbox

Есть такой блок с табами:

```css
.tabs__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  width: calc((100% - 8px)/2);
  border: 1px solid #2545B7;
  border-radius: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.tab.active {
  border: 1px solid #CD37E9;
  background: #CD37E9;
}

.tab .icon {
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  width: 14px;
}

.tab .tab__text {
  padding: 2px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs__wrapper">
    <div class="tab" id="mailtab" data-register-type="email">
        <img class="icon" src="./img/email_icon.svg" alt="email icon">
        <span class="tab__text">மின்னஞ்சல் வழியாக</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab active" id="phonetab" data-register-type="phone">
        <img class="icon" src="./img/phone_icon.svg" alt="phone icon">
        <span class="tab__text">தொலைபேசி மூலம்</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

У блока `.tab` есть свойство `justify-content: center`, и все внутри этого блока должно выравниваться по центру.

Но проблема в том, что по центру ничего не выравнивается. Блок `.tab__text` занимает все свободное пространство. И `.icon` сжимается и ширина иконки составляет 12рх вместо указанных 14рх.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я добавляю тег переноса `<br>`, то ширина `.tab__text` составляет ровно ширину текста, и все начинает выравниваться по центру.

```
<span class="tab__text">மின்னஞ்சல் <br> வழியாக</span>
<span class="tab__text">தொலைபேசி <br> மூலம்</span>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно сделать верстку, чтобы без тега `<br>` все работало правильно (все выравнивалось по центру, иконка не ужималась)?

Comment: Проблема не понятна так как у меня этот код работает как надо, все по центру. можно больше конкретики вашей проблемы. И с этим кодом табы не такие маленькие, а занимают пол экрана

Comment: Я приложи 2 скриншота. В первом не по центру, во втором, где тег переноса - по центру. Вот для наглядности увеличил ширину блока: http://joxi.ru/EA4x5BMc053PqA

Comment: Чтобы иконку не сжимало, задайте для нее `flex-shrink: 0`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте медиавыражение:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 430px) {
  .tab .tab__text {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```